# Active directory VBS to VB

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, active-directory

Hi I need to rewrite VBS script to VB file but I have trouble with following.

In VBS there is this:

```
Set OU = GetObject(LDAP_Path)
OU.Filter = Array("OrganizationalUnit")
For Each Item In OU
Description_OU = CStr(Item.Get("Description")) //Here is problem
...
```

In VB (2010) im using "System.DirectoryServices." because I need to work with Active Directory

My question:

***How it is that sometimes the Description_OU is empty and how can I test that in VB where Item is:***

```
Dim Item = System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

In another words: I cannot find anthing like **"Description" in .DirectoryEntry**

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item.Property("Description")(0).tostring
```

"Description" = key